# this.props.data is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I have pasted the code here. The problem is when using connect with mapstatetoprops and mapdispatchtoprops, i got this.props.CarDetails is not a function.. What i did wrong.. Also I want to know how to write actioncreator while clicking the button

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {carDetails} from '../actions/index';
import {Increment} from '../actions/updateValueAaction';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class SummaryItem extends Component{

   componentWillMount(){

      this.props.carDetails();
   }
   renderList(){

    return this.props.cars.map((car) => {

            return (

            <div className="col-sm-6 incrementer" >
              <div >
                  <span className="titleclass"> Hala </span>
                  <div className="input-group">
                      <span className="input-group-btn">
                          <button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-number incdec" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" value ={car.id} data-field="quant[1]">
                            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                        </button>
                      </span>
                      <input type="text" name="quant[1]"  value={car.ct} readOnly className="form-control input-number cthtvalue"  />

                  </div>
              </div>
                </div>
    </div>



    );
  });
}

render () {

    return (

        <div >{this.renderList()}</div>

        );
  }

onInputChange(e){console.log(e.target.value);
   // thisObj.onInputChange(thisObj.car.ct, event.target.value);
}

}
 function mapStateToProps(state){

   return {cars: state.cars.all};

  }

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){

return {
    routerActions:bindActionCreators({carDetails},dispatch),
    actions:bindActionCreators(Increment,dispatch)
   };
  }
   export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(SummaryItem);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you reduced the amount of code in your question to a show us a minimal example that reproduces the problem that you're having.

Comment: i have updated the code @Tom Fenech

Comment: There is no assignment of the property carDetails in the mapStateToProps function and thus unless it is passed directly by a parent component the property will not be available. It is a good habit to include the PropTypes validation during development to easier detect missing or wrongly "typed" props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way how to use mapDispatchToProps function.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(){
  return {carDetails, Increment};
}
```

After that it would be possible to call carDetails method by `this.props.carDetails()`.

Answer (score 2):

According to what you have written in mapDispatchToProps, you should call your action like this:

```
this.props.routerActions.carDetails()
```